# How to use the Google+ Hangouts API to get the Hangout On Air YouTube Live Video Embed URL?

Tags: youtube-javascript-api, google-hangouts

I created an google+ hangout app.
now i want to get a youtube LIVE video embeded url to display.
i tried below Js in my browser console after starting broadcast

```
gapi.hangout.onair.getYouTubeLiveId(); <br/>
```

but i am getting 'null' as the result.
i tried `gapi.hangout.onair.isBroadcasting();` 
but i am getting 'false' as the output in chrome browser console.
i tried `gapi.hangout.onair.isOnAirHangout();` 
but it got 'false' as the output. 
can anyone tell me the reason?

Comment: The API in question has shut down: https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/support-faq — for a modern version of this question, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/q/50605116/130638

Answer (score 1):

According to [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout.onair#gapi.hangout.onair.getYouTubeLiveId), getYouTubeLiveId() returns the YouTube Live ID for the Hangout *On Air*. *Returns null if the ID is not available or the Hangout is not a broadcast hangout*. Also, off-hand, I'm not sure it will provide the ID to a non-HOST. It's worth it to try as both Host of HoA and Participant and see if there's a difference.

I'm happy to test with you if you like.

Comment: From my understanding, the Google+ API that you mention has shut down. Is there a way to get this information in 2019?