# Can you derive a Hangout On Air join URL from the YouTube Live Streaming API?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, google-hangouts

As the [Google+ Hangouts API has shut down](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/support-faq), how can I use the [YouTube Live Streaming API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started) to:

1. Show me that a Hangout I started is broadcasting (I guess because it's broadcasting to YouTube)
2. Get the join URL for the Hangout on Air (the one that I hand out to others so they can join)?... or at least derive it from something that the API gives me?

Comment: Have you checked on this [SE post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17709/how-to-link-directly-to-a-google-hangout)?

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0, that's different. I'm asking if I can get, or derive, the Hangout URL from the YouTube API response.

Comment: Did you ever come to a solution for this? I am wanting this for the https://JordanBPeterson.community website.